# The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am trying to pass data to another screen but I am faced with this error.

The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

A number of users have posted a similar question, and I have actually gone through most of them but none of those given solutions seems to work in my case

I tried without the widget but it still didn't work. I mean I tried this *department.name*

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key, required this.department}) : super(key: key);
  final Department department;

  @override
  State<MainScreen> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    HomeView(
      department: Department(
          name: widget.department.name,// The error is here. 
          stream: '',
          description: '',
          author: '',
          availability: true,
          hod: '',
          totalNoBooks: 0),
    ),
    RequestedBooks(),
    ProfileScreen(),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Some Text Here"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I don't have a problem with the receiving screen. This is an excerpt of the code in the receiving screen

```
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeView({
    Key? key,
    required this.department,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Department department;

  @override
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState();
}
```

Comment: Adding late will provide lazy initialization or use initiate

Comment: adding late where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding widgets in the initstate

```dart
late List<Widget> _widgetOptions = [];
@override 
void initState(){
_widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    HomeView(
      department: Department(
          name: widget.department.name,// The error is here. 
          stream: '',
          description: '',
          author: '',
          availability: true,
          hod: '',
          totalNoBooks: 0),
    ),
    RequestedBooks(),
    ProfileScreen(),
  ];
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after, I feel this is an issue everyone encounters once then remembers forever lol. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can just include late like

```
late List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[ ..]
```

Note that it can't be done with class variables(static variables)

This is known as [**Lazy initialization**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69313493/10157127). Also it cant be be static

Also, you can use initState which is more common way of assigning data.

```dart
  late List<Widget> _widgetOptions ; //this can be static

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
      //...
    ];
  }
```